# How to list the contents of the variable VAR

Tags: shell

How to list the contents of the variable VAR

```
(
VAR="foo";
) &

echo $VAR; # I need to get "foo" ?
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If script can wait for variable assignment, you can try something like this:

```
tmp_pipe=`mktemp`
rm $tmp_pipe
mkfifo $tmp_pipe
(
VAR="foo";
echo $VAR > $tmp_pipe
) &

cat $tmp_pipe #or VAR=`cat $tmp_pipe`
rm $tmp_pipe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The shell that `$VAR` was created in has already exited.

Comment: and how to run the script in the background to win the variable VAR?

Comment: You can't. You can only access variables in the current process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access anything inside a subshell. You need some form of communication e.g. IPC between the subshell and main shell to ge the value.

Comment: subshel ​​=== script running in the background?

Comment: @VeronikaLipská Everything placed inside (). It doesn't necessarily need to be in a background. Everything placed inside () simply runs on a different child process under the main shell but inheriting all variables and states when executed.

Comment: and it's run differently in the background? like when I put it to function?

Comment: If you place it inside a function it won't be in a subshell or in a background. For clarity a subshell happens inside (). And a subshell gets into background if () is add with & at the end. A function on the other hand is simply a grouped set of commands but can have arguments and local variables so it is not necessarily something that goes into a subshell or background.